Screen flickering new install Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I bought a Lenovo ThinkCentre mini desktop and a Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. The fan is running extremely loudly and the screen is flickering. I have no additional drivers on the Software & Updates tab. Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2) is listed under graphics.
anoni@anoni-ThinkCentre-M910q:~$ glxinfo -B
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2) (0x1912)
    Version: 23.2.1
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 31984MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20



anoni@anoni-ThinkCentre-M910q:~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:134 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

I tried installing drivers but I don't think I did it correctly. I am novice at using linux commands so apologies for that.
